# Does Anemometer consumes power?

Tags: arduino-uno, power, solar

I planning to add an anemometer to my small solar weather station.
I designed this system to run from a single 3.7v rechargeable battery and a solar panel so I have to calculate in more power drain.

What I don't really understand is do these anemometers consume any external power or just give out a voltage by themselves?

This one doesn't even have consumption specified:

https://www.adafruit.com/products/1733

For this Supply voltage : 5V - 24VDC:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/JL-FSX2-4-20MA-0-5V-Output-Wind-Speed-Sensor-Wind-Speed-Transmitter-Anemometer-/331521148973?hash=item4d3033482d

Answer (score 1):

If it runs on electricity it definitely consumes power, its only how much the real question is.

Since you are working with electronics I am going to assume that you have a multimeter, if you dont have one. Its about time you did, doesnt cost much and will save you a ton of time debugging.

Nearly every multimeter has an onboard ammeter (the accuracy will be mentioned in the instructions manual). You can use this to determine the current consumed, have a look at a tutorial from [sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-multimeter/measuring-current) on how to do this

Comment: It's anemometer. It usually works just as a generator, a low power one but still.

Comment: If you watch the video on the adafruit link, she mentions that its probably got a hall effect sensor in it, the power you are supplying is to power the sensor on board. So yes, it does consume power.